# How to redirect output of Python script to terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal

How can I redirect my Python script output to one of the open terminal windows under Ubuntu? The script is spawned by KMail filtering rule.

Comment: Are you talking about virtual terminals or about terminal windows in X (similar to xterm)?

Comment: Talking about terminal in X, which I open by running terminal application from Applications->Accessories.

Comment: The typical solution (to what I think is your underlying problem) is to have the script append to a log file on disk, and then use `tail -f` on the log file in a terminal window when you want to watch things in (almost) real time. You'll want to rotate the log files once in a while.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Please put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a simple socket server would be one method… But I'd probably use fifos:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/my_fifo
$ cat producer.py
f = open("/tmp/my_fifo", "w")
f.write("hello, world!\n")
f.close()
```

Then you could read from it using `cat /tmp/my_fifo`

Or a simple log file:

```
$ cat producer.py
f = open("/tmp/my_log", "a")
f.write("hello, world!\n")
f.close()
```

Then you could read from it using `tail -f /tmp/my_log`

Comment: `os.mkfifo()` exists, so your first example could include that.

Comment: That's very true — I hadn't considered it.